# Need to Apply the Maximum Amount of a Budget over Several Rows until the Sum is 25000

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having trouble coming up with a formula to do this. I have a data set of over 1,700 budgets that I need to do this for. Each row does have a unique attribute further to the left but I cannot show it due to the nature of the data. But essentially I need to calculate the amount of the budget that gets applied toward the $25,000 in column M for each budget period. As you can see, sometimes it will happen over several periods and other times it will all be in the first year.

I am hoping there is a formula that I can enter into the blank cell below each instance of $25,000 in column M (I have a macro that can select all of those cells at once and then just Ctrl + Enter to apply it to each instance) and then fill down.

How the spreadsheet looks:

[image: spreadsheet current state]

Desired Result (done manually for an example):

[image: desired result]

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

I can come up with a formula to do this for a single budget but I have over 1,700 budgets with a variable number of years (even though the two examples I show both have 3 years) and I cannot figure out how to do a running sum with a variable number of years while only allowing the total to reach 25000.

Comment: Please provide sample data in [Table Markdown](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) format. Just copy your data from Excel, generate it and copy it back to your question leaving a blank line. It helps to reproduce the sample and it helps you because your question gains more attention and possible more answers. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Powerquery could return the desired column

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each if [Column1]="Total" then [Index] else null),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Down", {"Custom"}, {{"data", each  
    let #"Added Index1" = Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index1", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Cum Total" = Table.AddColumn( #"Added Index1", "CumTotal", each List.Sum(List.RemoveFirstN(List.FirstN(#"Added Index1" [Column3],[Index1]),1))??0),
    max=#"Added Index1"[Column4]{0}, 
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Cum Total", "New", each if [Column1]="Total" then max else if [Column3]+[CumTotal]<max then [Column3] else if  max-[CumTotal]>0 then   max-[CumTotal] else 0),
    #"Remove Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Index", "Custom", "Index1", "CumTotal"})
    in #"Remove Columns", type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", Table.ColumnNames(Source)&{"New"},Table.ColumnNames(Source)&{"New"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded data",{"Custom"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
=LET(r, XMATCH(1,NOT(ISNUMBER(J:J))*(ROW(J:J)>ROW()))-1,
     t, INDEX(M:M,ROW()-1),
DROP( REDUCE(0,INDEX(L:L,ROW()):INDEX(L:L,r),
      LAMBDA(a,b,
      VSTACK(a,
             IF(SUM(a)+b>t,
             t-SUM(a),
              b)))),
      1))
```

This formula would also work, pasted in column D at the start of the amounts, to spill up to the next total.

Comment: Really? `NOT(ISNUMBER(J:J))*(ROW(J:J)>ROW()` has to process more than 2 million cells for every single iteration. I pasted that construction into just 50 cells (`A1:AX1`) and my machine nearly crashed.

Comment: @JosWoolley `=LET(start,NOW(),r, XMATCH(1,NOT(ISNUMBER(J:J))*(ROW(J:J)>ROW()))-1,     t, INDEX(M:M,ROW()-1),i,DROP( REDUCE(0,INDEX(L:L,ROW()):INDEX(L:L,r),      LAMBDA(a,b,      VSTACK(a,             IF(SUM(a)+b>t,             t-SUM(a),              b)))),      1),TEXT(NOW()-start,"s.000"))` gives a result under a second on my phone for data in row 2 to 1000. https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjnNv.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that 148,195.00 is in cell L1, here is an old school formula that may be pasted into cell M2 and copied down to M8 `=IF(J1="total",MIN(L2,M1),MIN(L2,INDEX(M$1:M1,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(M$1:M1)/(J$1:J1="total"),1))-SUM(M1:INDEX(M$1:M1,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(M$1:M1)/(J$1:J1="total"),1)+1))))`

Note that the formula will overwrite the second instance of 25,000.00 which will need to be reentered into cell M5.